# Asus X55c Fn key not working

Tags: 12.10, asus

Because Fn key is not working i cant enable the wifi and also change the brightness of the screen. Fn key is partly working for sound up and down and screen off
I have installed Ubuntu 12.10.
Laptop is Asus X55C
Regarding WiFi i think Wlan card driver installation will also be required. Kindly help on these 2 Issues ,I don't want Windows ..that is y

Answer (score 1):

I solved my 2 problems
1) for brightness ,use xbacklight
2) Wifi , Ralink Wifi driver installed.

But the screen sharpess seems to be less for ubuntu.. 
Any idea How to increase sharpness of screen?

Comment: If it doesn't appear "sharp" it tends to indicate the display is set at the wrong resolution. Open the monitor/display settings and change it around.